# iOS: Read state of AssistiveTouch feature

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, accessibility, accessibility-api

I'm looking for a way to determine the state of the "AssistiveTouch" accessibility feature in iOS5. I need some kind of function to checked whether it is enabled or not - any ideas? Couldn't find anything in the accessibility documentation so far... undocumented ways are ok too, if there's no official way yet.
More specific, I need to find out if a recorded gesture is played at the current time, that's why I'm asking.

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Hey, have you find anything that might help to determine whether the assistive touch is enabled?

Comment: Nothing so far, sorry.